# Sending reply to service message in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How i can send service reply in windows phone. For example, if we are using service request with windows phone like *414# and press call button service response is popping out in a message box with contents like,

1. Press 1 for activate 4G service
2. Press 2 for deactivate 4G service
3. Press 3 for 4G settings

But, there is no no input option is available in that message box, If we press ok to message box, the message box disappears and the action cancels without any confirmation. Is there any settings present in windows phone to make this working. If it is a limitation of OS please give me an alternative solution to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Stez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot piggy back on the Phone Dialer app to launch your app in WP7/WP8.

You'll have to write a normal app end-to-end to do what you'd like to do.